# docker run with volume changes directory permission to root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

When I am running docker image, the artifacts directory which I mount, gets root permission. 
I want the artifacts to have the same permission as user. 
Is it possible to pass user as an argument while running docker image such that it creates artifacts directory with particular user permission?

This is how I run docker:

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined -it -v /home/artifacts:/artifacts dock_img

drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4.0K Nov 16 13:58 artifacts
```

As this artifacts gets root permission, I am unable to process on it from my user login. Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you use the root user inside the container.

You can use the `-u` param to set the user you use outside (e.g. `` -u `id -u $USER` ``), but if you need root inside the container, you have to chown it manually.

Comment: I tried adding -u $USER while running docker but it gives error : Unable to find user <>
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 7bc5461c4d04cd42f9f5b54c9213bdb44bfc2841454953ac66ae64c0cdc4a53d: [8] System error: Unable to find user <>. I haven't added any USER in dockerfile, will -u option work without adding USER in dockerfile?

Comment: Yes it should work, but it seems like your console dont Support subcommands in backticks. Try to use the uid directly

Comment: Now I am getting different error with name : root@onl-dev:/data/sept15/target-docker# docker run -u <name> -it x
docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user <name>: no matching entries in passwd file. But I see the entry : root@onl-dev:/data/sept15/target-docker# cat  /etc/passwd | grep <name>
<name>:x:1012:1012:,,,:/home/<name>:/bin/bash

Comment: I tried running with uid also: "docker run -u 1004 -it -v /home/artifacts:/artifacts temp" but still it creates artifacts folder with root: "drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4.0K Nov 16 19:26 artifacts"

Comment: It seems like that the problem with `-u` is that the user dont exists inside the container. So you have to chown it or create the user with `useradd` and if you do that you can also use the `USER` instruction.